# imageView tapGesture vs button touchUpInside , with didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

When I use inside a `TableViewCell` an `UIImageView` and `tapGesture`.
If I tap directly on the image it trigger :

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath

my_image_tap_deletage
```

If I used a `UIButton` with `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` inside a `TableViewCell`
if I tap directly on the button it trigger :

```
my_button_tap_delegate
```

---

I know I can use `UIButton` with image on it, instead of `UIImageView`, but still.

Questions:

1.Why there is such different in the event triggering  ?

2.How can i make the image act like the button, to trigger only the control event without  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

UPDATE:
I don't know if it's important, but i just want to notice that
I'm creating the UITableViewCell from xib  + subclass.

UPDATE 2 :
Well, half of blame on me.
I forget to mention one more thing.
I set the gesture to gesture.numberOfTapsRequiered=2;

If it's 1, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called, and it's O.K

If it's 2, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called. i tried with gesture.cancelsTouchesInView=YES/NO (both..) and the didSelec still called.

Maybe with 2 taps, the SDK decide that the didSelect will be called no matter what ?

Hope I'm clear here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set the gesture property cancelsTouchesInView towards NO? If so, make sure it is set towards YES.

Answer (score 1):

As for as I've noticed, if you've done every thing correct to add the image view to the table view cell and if you  tap on the `UIImageView`, it should only call the imageView's action, not the table view's *didSelectRowAtIndexPath:* delegate method.